# Get the value of a child in firebase using nodejs TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong. I am trying to write a firebase function to send a notification. That part works, but I am trying to get the value of a particular child. Yet I keep getting the following error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined"

This is my server-side code:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_key}').onWrite((data, context)=>{
    const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
    const notification_key = context.params.notification_key;
    console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', receiver_user_id);
    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    const original = data.after.val();
    console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.notification_key, original);
    const sender_fullname = snapshot.child('notifying_user_fullname').val();
    console.log('fullname value: ', sender_fullname);

    if(!data.after.val()){
        console.log('A notification has been deleted: ', notification_key);
        return null;
    }

    const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/tokens/${receiver_user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return DeviceToken.then(result=>{
        const token_id = result.val();
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: sender_fullname,
                body: "You have a new message!",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response=>{
            console.log('Message has been sent');
        });
    });

});
```

The snapshot prints out just fine. And when I remove the snapshot and sender_fullname constants the notification is delivered just fine. But, like I said, I keep getting a TypeError message when the code is executed this way. Does anyone know how to get the value of a child at a certain location in realtime database. If it helps, this is what the data snapshot looks like:

[image]

If anyone can help that would be great. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable `snapshot` that was never defined, at least not that you're showing here.  Here's where you're using it:

```
const sender_fullname = snapshot.child('notifying_user_fullname').val();
```

Trying to call method on something that's not defined would give you that error message.

Comment: I have been tinkering with the code, I might have deleted that line. I have tried const snapshot = data.after.val(); and const snapshot = data; and I also tried const original = data.after.val();
    console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.notification_key, original);
    const sender_fullname = original.child('notifying_user_fullname').val(); but I would get an error like this: TypeError: original.child is not a function. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Hi, i have  the same problem, to get the value from a child field, could you solve this?